# Avisar si ya existe en la base de datos un registro antes de ingresar, filtrando por tres condiciones. en visual basic y sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Estimados muy buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente dilema, no consigo hacer que en mi sistema en visual basic con base de datos sql server, al momento de querer grabar un nuevo dato en la tabla, de existir el mismo, me avise de ello, cumpliendo tres condiciones a la vez (AND):

1. Qué no tenga el mismo número de documento
2. Qué no pertenezca a la misma área
3. Qué no sea un documento del mismo año

solo me resulta con una condición, haciéndolo de la siguiente forma, pero al poner las 3 no me resulta:

```
MiConexion.Open()
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM documentos WHERE numerodocumento = '" & TextBoxNumDoc.Text & "'"

Com = New SqlCommand(SQL, MiConexion)
Rs = Com.ExecuteReader()

Rs.Read()
LabelTomaNumeroDoc.Text = Rs(0)
Rs.Close()
MiConexion.Close()

If LabelTomaNumeroDoc.Text = 0 Then
   Conectar.sqlconectar()
   Conectar.IngresarDoc()
```

Comment: podrias aclarar porque no te funciona con mas condiciones?

Comment: se salta las demas,,,, al poner el siguiente codigo: SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM documentos WHERE numerodocumento = '" & TextBoxNumDoc.Text & "'" AND area = '" & TextBoxArea.Text & "' AND anio = '" & TextBoxAnio.Text & "'

Answer (score 0):

Amigo estas haciendo un paso menos para extraer el valor, te falta algo así:

```
       If reader.HasRows Then
            Do While reader.Read()
                LabelTomaNumeroDoc.Text = Rs(0)
            Loop
        Else
            LabelTomaNumeroDoc.Text = "0"
        End If
```

Prueba lo que agrego, el error es no leer bien el resultado.

Comment: Eso me funcionaria incluso si pongo 2 condiciones mas? ejemplo: SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM documentos WHERE numerodocumento = '" & TextBoxNumDoc.Text & "'" AND area = '" & TextBoxArea.Text & "' AND anio = '" & TextBoxAnio.Text & "'